# Catch event when user was kicked from a telegram channel

Tags: telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

How to catch event when user was kicked from a telegram channel using PyTelegramBotAPI?
I tried to use chat_member_handler, but it works only with chat, not with channel or supergroup